# return more than one data type

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-phone-7, generics, casting

I query-ing this from entity framework using WCF, and i want to use the data in phone client side, may i know how can i query more than one data type from the WCF function ?

```
[OperationContract]
string LoginUser(string email, string password);
```

IService.cs

```
        public string LoginUser(string email, string password)
    {
        string query = @"SELECT VALUE tblUser FROM MyEntities.tblUsers AS tblUser WHERE tblUser.email = @email AND tblUser.password = @password";
        ObjectParameter[] parameters = new ObjectParameter[2];
        parameters[0] = new ObjectParameter("email", email);
        parameters[1] = new ObjectParameter("password", password);

        using (var context = new SteamKingEntities())
        {
            ObjectQuery<string> results = context.CreateQuery<string>(query, parameters);
            foreach (string result in results)
            {
                if (result != null)
                {
                    return result;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

IService.svc.cs

```
        public Login()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _serviceClient = new Service1Client();
        _serviceClient.LoginUserCompleted += new EventHandler<LoginUserCompletedEventArgs>(_serviceClient_LoginUserCompleted);

    }

    private void loginBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _serviceClient.LoginUserAsync(txtEmail.Text, txtPassword.Password);
    }

    private void _serviceClient_LoginUserCompleted(object sender, LoginUserCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Error == null && e.Result != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Welcome " + e.Result + "!");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Error.Message + " Couldn't Login, Please try again =D");
        }
    }
```

Login.xaml.cs

I want to return the entire table from Entity Framework and allow me to process one by one in Window Phone side.

I guess i need to do some modification to the IService side but i seriously don't know how because i'm new to phone development and used to Linq to SQL. Can you please guide me on how to make something like type for the return, Please. Thank you.

**Update**

The error i get `There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter http://tempuri.org/:LoginUserResult.  Please see InnerException for more details.`

i was modified the code into the way stated in [WCF Custom Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1974562/wcf-service-returning-custom-objects) but i could not deserialize it... i guess the problem came from the WP part, **how could i deserialize the result** ?

Comment: I don't understand which types you want to return

Comment: This is the error i get : The specified cast from a materialized 'WCFServiceWebRole1.tblUser' type to the 'System.String' type is not valid.

Comment: What in the InnerException? Did you refresh service reference?

Comment: What is the type of the column VALUE of the tblUser table?

Comment: @gabba , yep. I did refresh and debug the wcf , I can get the specific data for specific data member. Then when I debut with phone, I will get this...

Comment: @gabba, Please read the new question here for the error i get, and please guide me out. Thank you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10570253/there-was-an-error-while-trying-to-deserialize-parameter-http-tempuri-org-log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733070.aspx) or you can use [custom-objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1974562/wcf-service-returning-custom-objects)

Comment: i was edit into the way the reference but may i know how to solve the new problem ? Thx for reply

Comment: now I not sure what should I do with the phone part, by letting my phone know to read the data type I want and deserialize the line of data into specific data by data...

Answer (score 1):

You need to use data contract:

```
[DataContract]
    public class ReturnType
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Pass { get; set; }
    }
```

in service it would look like this:

```
[OperationContract]
    Entities.ReturnType[] SelectTopUser(int countOfTop);
```

the return type can be an entity framework type

Comment: i was created a class with name UserData and created data contract inside, then change my operation contract into [OperationContract]
UserData LoginUser(string email, string password);
but still couldn't make it...

Comment: also you need to refresh service reference in client code (phone side). With what difficulties you have run?

Comment: now I not sure what should I do with the phone part, by letting my phone know to read the data type I want and deserialize the line of data into specific data by data...