# wcf response format transformation

Tags: xml, string, wcf

I have wcf function that returns a string.

Then response xml is presented as:

```
<string>ok</string>
```

But I want to get this response as

```
<myOwnStrName>ok</myOwnStrName>
```

How would I achieve this in WCF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by defining your own custom types, like below

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1974599/1196411

Comment: I used that notation. But it has also extra issues such as namespaces.

Comment: I need only return a string not a class